# Regarding app published in google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I want to know that it is possible to track how many no of devices app will installed and how many of them are uninstalled after installing the app. 
I mean that can I get the no of the app installed currently.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with anything SO is for as defined in the Help Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visit [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) or install the [Google Play Console App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.playconsole) & view detailed statistics of your app, including but not limited to installs, uninstalls, active devices etc!